# How to use For loop in Robot framework, to fetch application login Details from an excel ? give me some example with latest Robot framework 3.1

Tags: for-loop, robotframework

I'm new to Robot framework and i want to know how to login to a application using data's in excel, using For loop.

how to make use this,

```
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements_list}
    Keyword    arg
END
```

Comment: may I see your excel data?

Answer (score 1):

Example you have below data in excel :

[image]

and here a sample for loop to get value from this excel file:

```
open excel    ${PATH_EXCEL}
    ${exp_row_count}    get row count   sheet1
    ${exp_row_count}    evaluate        ${exp_row_count}-1
    :For    ${i}    IN RANGE     1       ${exp_row_count}
    \   ${user}    Read Cell Data By Name    sheet1    A${i}
    \   ${password}    Read Cell Data By Name    sheet1    B${i}
```

PS: here a library excels that I use for example.

```
pip install robotframework-excellibrary
```

Comment: Hi Sid,i'm using "robotframework-excellib 1.1.0" vesion in that 'get row count' & 'Read Cell Data By Name' is not available, so which version can i make use of ?

Comment: Like i mentioned u is install pip install robotframework-excellibrary

Comment: i tried to install below error occurred,
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: I think it supports only python 2.7